# spacy instead of nltk for POS tagging

Tags: python, nltk, spacy, part-of-speech

I have a function based on nltk.pos_tag that filters out collocations from text for only Adjective (JJ) and Noun (NN) together.

```
f1=u'this is my random text'

tokens = word_tokenize(f1)
bigramFinder = nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
bigram_freq = bigramFinder.ngram_fd.items()
bigramFreqTable = pd.DataFrame(list(bigram_freq), columns=['bigram','freq']).sort_values(by='freq', ascending=False)
print(bigramFreqTable)

def rightTypes(ngram):
    first_type = ('JJ')
    second_type = ('NN')
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(ngram)
    if tags[0][1] in first_type and tags[1][1] in second_type:
        return True
    else:
        return False

filtered_bi = bigramFreqTable[bigramFreqTable.bigram.map(lambda x: rightTypes(x))]
print(filtered_bi)
```

I would like to use `spacy` method instead of `nltk.pos_tag`. Below is example code from `spacy` documentation.

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.examples import sentences 

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(sentences[0])
print(doc.text)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_)
```

I tried different solutions, for example    `tags=[(X.text, X.tag_) for Y in nlp(ngram).ents for X in Y]` but have errors... Could you please help to use spacy instead of nltk?

Answer (score 1):

Using spaCy's `Matcher`, you can [create custom rules](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) you want to match against.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
# Add match ID "HelloWorld" with no callback and one pattern
pattern = [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"IS_PUNCT": True}, {"LOWER": "world"}]
matcher.add("HelloWorld", None, pattern)

doc = nlp("Hello, world! Hello world!")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

You can use a pattern such as:
`[{"POS": "JJ"}, {"POS": NN}]` to meet your requirements.